# How to copy and rename a VIEW/SP programmatically in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know you can right-click on the selected VIEW/SP and select CREATE-TO, and you can just copy the generated script. But this has to be done via a SQL Client.

What I wish to do is that whenever there is an update on the VIEW/SP by my vendor, I would like to perform the backup of the affected VIEW/SP before running the ALTER VIEW/SP command from my vendor. I wish to do this using script rather than human interface so as to reduce the risk of human errors.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = (    SELECT  Routine_Definition
                FROM    (   SELECT  Routine_Catalog, Routine_Schema, Routine_Name, Routine_Definition
                            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
                            WHERE   Routine_type  = 'PROCEDURE'
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  Table_Catalog, Table_Schema, Table_Name, View_Definition
                            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
                        ) def
                WHERE   Routine_Catalog = 'YourDatabase'
                AND     Routine_Schema = 'YourSchema'
                AND     Routine_Name = 'YourView/SP'
            )

IF @SQL IS NULL
    RETURN

EXEC SP_RENAME 'YourDatabase.YourSchema.YourView/SP', 'NewName', 'OBJECT'
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for SP, but not for VIEW. Apparently there is no routine_type = VIEW in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES table.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realy check this before posting... I've updated the answer to now include views as well as Stored procedures and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the link where you can find how to create/alter/delete Stored procedure using C# code

You can create front end form(GUI) in C# or your desired technology and in in this form 
you vendor enter the detail of stored procedures.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162190.aspx

Following are the scripts that you run in Database to find the detail of changes/Created stored procedures

```
SELECT name 'Alterd Procedures'
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEDIFF(D,modify_date, GETDATE()) < 5

SELECT name 'Created Procedures'
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEDIFF(D,create_date, GETDATE()) < 5
```

5 is the no of days, you can change this according to your need

you can change 'P' to 'V' for views

Comment: Actually what I meant by programmatically is via SQL script. I am not well verse in development languages.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Or you could just use the more appropriate system catalog views, `sys.procedures` or `sys.tables` .....

Comment: Thanks for the updated scripts. I like the scripts, it sort of showing the audit trails of which SPs were changed. However, in the case of where I want to roll back the altered SP, how can I do it?